# Sagemaker Torch Installation Failing

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I try to install torch on Sagemaker with the shebang-command in python.

```
!pip install torch==1.6.0
```

However, I can only run a notebook once on that specific version. The next time i install that torch version using the notebook, it fails.

The exact error message is:

```
Collecting torch==1.6.0
Killed
```

The only workaround would be to install slightly different versions for next notebook runs.